# Visibility map inside polygons

Tags: c++, math, canvas, polygon, path-finding

I just started working on a project at work and I'm not sure where to start. I have a polygon map and I have to create a visibility graph inside of the map so we can run a pathfinding algorithm on it. There are multiple polygons that add up to one big map with different weights on them. Different users are only allowed to traverse across polygons that have a lower weight than themselves. I've been looking for resources tackling this problem but can't seem to find any good ones. 
If you have some experience or any idea where I should look, a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon